# Julia Symbolics.gradient replaces variables incorrectly

Tags: julia

I want to use Symbolics.jl to calculate gradient of a function. I define function F(x,y,z,a,b,c) as a Symbolics.gradient of function u(x,y,z,a,b,c).

```
using Symbolics

@variables x, y, z, a, b, c

u(x, y, z, a, b, c) = a*(1 - 1/(1+(z/c)^2) *  exp(-2*(x^2 + y^2)/(b^2 * (1+(z/c)^2))))
F(x, y, z, a,b,c) = Symbolics.gradient(u(x,y,z,a,b,c), [x,y,z])
```

I get unexpected behaviour when trying to input numbers in function F. For example, I expect F(0,0,0,1,1,1) to be equal to F(x->0,0,0,1,1,1) or F(0,0,0,1,1,1)=(0,0,0), which is not the case.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

While it is unclear and I'm not an expert in Symbolics, I think the problem is you intend `u` to be a symbolic expression, but instead you've written Julia functions.

So the code is evaluating `u(0,0,0,1,1,1)` first, which is 0.0, and thus executing `Symbolics.gradient(0.0, [1, 1, 1])`.

Instead, omit variables names from the definition of `u` - the point of the `@variables` expression is to inform Symbolics of the variable names.

```
u = a*(1 - 1/(1+(z/c)^2) *  exp(-2*(x^2 + y^2)/(b^2 * (1+(z/c)^2))))
Symbolics.gradient(u, [x,y,z])

3-element Vector{Num}:
      (4a*x*exp((-2(x^2 + y^2)) / ((b^2)*(1 + (z / c)^2)))) / ((b^2)*((1 + (z / c)^2)^2))
      (4a*y*exp((-2(x^2 + y^2)) / ((b^2)*(1 + (z / c)^2)))) / ((b^2)*((1 + (z / c)^2)^2))
 a*((-2z*((-exp((-2(x^2 + y^2)) / ((b^2)*(1 + (z / c)^2)))) / ((1 + (z / c)^2)^2))) / (c^2) + (2(b^2)*z*exp((-2(x^2 + y^2)) / ((b^2)*(1 + (z / c)^2)))*((-2(x^2 + y^2)) / ((b^4)*((1 + (z / c)^2)^2)))) / ((c^2)*(1 + (z / c)^2)))
```

Comment: Symbolics.jl is supposed to work with Julia functions; however, there might be an issue with them here.

Comment: Maybe the issue is just that you're not supposed to plug concrete values in if you want a symbolic evaluation? If all the values passed to `u` are present, there's no function anymore, just a value.